# What objects make up each of the line items in the "Current File Storage Usage" section?

Tags: file-storage

When you navigate to Setup -> Data-> Storage Usage, there's a breakdown of current file storage usage. What objects correspond to each of the line items?

These are my guesses:

1. Response History     ?
2. Translate Jobs   ?
3. Response Templates   ?
4. Report Result ?
5. Blobs    ?
6. Replies  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_reply.htm
7. Questions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_question.htm
8. Knowledge Articles (unclear if this is https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticle.htm or https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm )
9. Attachments: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm
10. Content Bodies: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm
11. LogSearchResult  ?
12. Site.com Assets   ?
13. Photos   ?
14. Documents: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm

Comment: A bit surprised to see multiple downvotes here with no explanation. I guess the reason may be lack of research? It would have been better as an ask-and-answer combo, but still seems like a decent question to ask.

Comment: @AdrianLarson me to. I've spun my wheels on this, and created a case with Salesforce to no avail. I've done some research in understanding the 28 objects associated with content and still am not finding anything officially documented

Comment: I mean a decent number of them seem obvious, only a few jump out as head scratchers.